# Lost Sound - Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: dual-boot, sound, cinnamon

System/OS details:  Dual Boot Ubuntu 23.04 and Windows 11(on separate drives)
HP OMEN Desktop. Ubuntu Desktop is configured for Cinnamon (Latest Upgrade).

Background Info:

I installed and been running this setup for several months and sound was working perfectly but the last time I booted into Ubuntu the sound was gone.

I update & upgrade every time I boot into Ubuntu. The sound works perfectly in Windows 11 but for some reason, I have lost sound in Ubuntu. I have checked the obvious (eg. mute & volume settings).

The sound settings displays the Device Out: Line Out Built-in Audio & the profile is Analog Stereo.  I executed the Test Sound which worked previously, doesn't output any sound.
None of the system sounds work anymore either.

I researched numerous "Solutions" sources and have not had any of those to work. Since I am a relatively new Linux user, don't tinker with system settings and have not installed any new programs. I am at a total dead end. Please help!

---

added Info
Here are the results of some tests that were suggested from previous web searches.  I am totally ignorant as to what the results actually indicate.

pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-09-08 14:34:48 CDT; 21min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
Main PID: 1915 (pipewire)
Tasks: 2 (limit: 38030)
Memory: 6.8M
CPU: 229ms
CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
└─1915 /usr/bin/pipewire

Sep 08 14:34:48 dogman-OMEN-by-HP-40L-Gaming-Desktop-GT21-1xxx systemd[1908]: Started pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service.
Sep 08 14:34:48 dogman-OMEN-by-HP-40L-Gaming-Desktop-GT21-1xxx pipewire[1915]: mod.rt: Can't find org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop. Is xdg-desktop-portal running?
Sep 08 14:34:48 dogman-OMEN-by-HP-40L-Gaming-Desktop-GT21-1xxx pipewire[1915]: mod.rt: found session bus but no portal
~

### ***********************************************************************~$ lspci -nnk |grep -A3 -i aud
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a50] (rev 11)
DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8a97]
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 21/23 HDMI/DP Audio Controller [1002:ab28]
Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 21/23 HDMI/DP Audio Controller [1002:ab28]
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_inteldogman@dogman-OMEN-by-HP-40L-Gaming-~$ lsmod | grep -i snd
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   192512  1
snd_hda_codec_generic   118784  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl    16384  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common   188416  1 snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
soundwire_intel        57344  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_pci            24576  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof               311296  3 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_sof_utils          20480  1 snd_sof
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_ext_core       36864  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    77824  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_core          417792  4 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     94208  2
snd_compress           32768  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          61440  2
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         204800  6 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hda_core          139264  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               192512  11 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            53248  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                94208  9 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              49152  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
snd                   135168  20 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
***********************************************************************~$ fuser /dev/snd/*
/dev/snd/controlC0:   1949
/dev/snd/controlC1:   1949
/dev/snd/seq:         1946

---

~$ lsof /dev/snd/*
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
pipewire  1946 dogman   50u   CHR  116,1      0t0  580 /dev/snd/seq
pipewire  1946 dogman   51u   CHR  116,1      0t0  580 /dev/snd/seq
wireplumb 1949 dogman   31u   CHR 116,19      0t0 1078 /dev/snd/controlC0
wireplumb 1949 dogman   35u   CHR  116,9      0t0 1044 /dev/snd/controlC1

---

04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Sandisk Corp Western Digital WD Black SN850X NVMe SSD [15b7:5030] (rev 01)
dogman@dogman-OMEN-by-HP-40L-Gaming-Desktop-GT21-1xxx:~$ [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyCx1.png)

---

Here are more test results:
~$ lsmod | grep -i snd
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   192512  1
snd_hda_codec_generic   118784  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl    16384  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common   188416  1 snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
soundwire_intel        57344  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_pci            24576  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof               311296  3 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_sof_utils          20480  1 snd_sof
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_ext_core       36864  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    77824  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_core          417792  4 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     94208  2
snd_compress           32768  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          61440  2
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         204800  6 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hda_core          139264  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               192512  11 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            53248  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                94208  9 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              49152  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
snd                   135168  20 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
***********************************************************************~$ fuser /dev/snd/*
/dev/snd/controlC0:   1949
/dev/snd/controlC1:   1949
/dev/snd/seq:         1946

---

~$ lsof /dev/snd/*
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
pipewire  1946 dogman   50u   CHR  116,1      0t0  580 /dev/snd/seq
pipewire  1946 dogman   51u   CHR  116,1      0t0  580 /dev/snd/seq
wireplumb 1949 dogman   31u   CHR 116,19      0t0 1078 /dev/snd/controlC0
wireplumb 1949 dogman   35u   CHR  116,9      0t0 1044 /dev/snd/controlC1
dogman@dogman-OMEN-by-HP-40L-Gaming-Desktop-GT21-1xx

---

I hope somebody reads and responds.  This issue is really discouraging because I didn't do anything to the system, the sound used to work perfectly for several months, after the installation of Ubuntu 23.04. I did no tweeking (because I realize that I am totally ignorant about the inter workings of Linux... and the fact that **the sound is working flawlessly on Windows 11**.

TIA

More information:

~$ pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 64
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: dogman
Host Name: dogman-OMEN-by-HP-40L-Gaming-Desktop-GT21-1xxx
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.79)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
Cookie: 7401:edbf

Update:  I installed ALSA Mixer and after making adjustments to the various modes, I was able to get the faintest output but no where near functional levels.

pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start

yielded no improvement.

I have no idea how to reinstall the audio/sound drivers.  The only information that I could find was for an much older version of Ubuntu.

Comment: What does `pulseaudio &` do?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) And provide us more detail. A screenshot of your sound settings would be helpful.

Comment: @rando `pulseaudio &` runs pulseaudio in the background. That command would fail because it normally is already running by a Daemon.

Comment: @stumblebee It may not be running on Dogman45's system.

Comment: I apologize for the long delay in response; I am having a significant health issue that is taking precedence so please don't think my absences are lack of interest.  I truly appreciate any help from this forum.

Comment: Here are the results of some tests that were suggested from previous web searches.  I am totally ignorant as to what the results actually indicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit.  Thunar was causing not only the sound issue but network file transmission.  I used synaptic for total removal and all issues were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the sound service:
You can try restarting the sound service to resolve temporary issues. Use the following commands to restart PulseAudio, a common sound server in Ubuntu:

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

Check individual application settings:
Make sure the applications you are using to play sound have the correct audio settings and are using the appropriate output device. I even tried connecting external speakers to conduct tests.

Verify sound output:
Use a command like `aplay` or `speaker-test` to check if you can play sounds directly from the command line. For example:

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

Check for errors in the logs:
Review system logs, especially audio logs, for error messages. You can use the `dmesg` command to check kernel messages.

Update or reinstall drivers:
If the problem persists after following the previous steps, consider updating or reinstalling your audio drivers.

I had to reinstall the drivers, and in that case, they started working again.